# Remote Deploy Java EE to Linux Wildfly Server

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee-7, wildfly-9

I had completed my java ee application with postgres on my Windows development machine. Now, I would like to deploy it to CentOS linux.

However, the concept wasn't as straight forward as I think.

I had to export my project as .war file, then install Wildfly, install Postgres, setup Datasource in standalone.xml, then deploy in Wildfly Console. It seems too much work (especially setting up datasource).

I used to work with Ruby on Rails, where we have a git source control, and we just git pull on the server to deploy, but things don't seems that straight forward for Java EE.

Am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: No, you are not missing anything. There are different ways of implementing things like a datasource and the actual deploy though. Have you googled any of that?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a Maven app, you can use the Wilfly Maven plugin to deploy on a Wildfly server running locally or on a remote server: https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/

Here is an excellent blog post that describes how to configure your Maven settings and your pom: https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/